# Tour page summary - we're not a Q&A site

Tags: discussion, status-completed, new-users, help-center

Here's what our Tour page says right now:

> Code Golf Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of programming puzzles and their solutions.

We're not a Q&A site. Our tour page probably shouldn't say that. In fact, I'd like to make a much clearer distinction that *we are not like the rest of the SE network*. I am able to edit it, so what should we change it to?

---

Also, should it contain something about the Sandbox? There's no other logical place to put it in the tour page, and at the bottom of the tour page, there's an "Ask Question" button directly, so new users will see that before anything mentioning the Sandbox. I'm not sure about this idea, since it's not really part of the "what we're about" which is what the first section seems like it should be about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Code Golf Stack Exchange is a site for code golfers and coding challenge enthusiasts. It's built, maintained and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of sites. Unlike most other sites in the network, we are not a Q&A site. Instead of asking questions and posting answers, we work together to build a collection of coding competitions and solutions

A modified version of the original text, changed to empathise:

- "code golfers and coding challenge enthusiasts" vs "programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers", as we've moved away from "programming puzzles" with the new site name
- I added a sentence specifying that we're different from most sites in the network, as well as specifically stating that we aren't a Q&A site
- The final sentence is simply a rewording of the current version

Comment: Not sure if this wording would be better, but possibly avoiding repetition: "Instead of asking questions and posting answers, we work together ot build a collection of coding challenges and competitions and solutions (/ submissions)". (At least, "together" probably doesn't need to be repeated :P)

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Good advice, I've edited it slightly to use that wording :)

Comment: I disagree with 'competitive coding enthusiasts', makes it seem like it's a good place to ask for help with competitive programming, which it really is not.

Comment: I agree with rak1507 here. "Competitive coding/programming" (CP) commonly means something like ICPC, Topcoder, Codeforces etc. I think "coding challenge enthusiasts" is slightly better (which also agrees with the full name of the site), though it doesn't completely avoid the CP context.

Comment: @Bubbler Fair enough, I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this site is not a "Question & Answer" site but more like a "Challenge & Answer site", meaning pretty much none of the challenges are actual questions but more like challenges/tasks to be completed. The only other site I know of like this on the SE network is Puzzling, but many puzzles are presented as questions.